# Make div with dynamic background img url a link

Tags: php, html, css

I have this PHP:

```
<?php $image = "IMAGES/default_profile_img.png"; ?>
```

This is the linked `div`

```
<a href="page.php">
    <div class="profile_img" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $image; ?>)">
        // image itself displays correctly
    </div>
</a>
```

The `div` above is subject to this CSS:

```
.profile_img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The `div` displays in the correct size and the `$image` displays correctly in the `div`.
However the `div` does not present any linking abilities whatsoever. In essence, the `<a>` tag is not working.

Does this have something to do with the `img(url)` being dynamic?
What might cause the `<a>` tag to not work in this instance?

Comment: Clear the `float:left` in the parent container or remove it.

Comment: Or remove the div, and style the `a` element instead. (The div seems to serve no purpose here, at least in this example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the `a` tag within the `div`

```
<div class="profile_img" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $image; ?>)">
   <a href="page.php">
   </a>
</div>
```

And give the `a` the css properties to fill the entire `div`

```
 .profile_img a {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```